# NSPredicate format for check the 2 array and filter those array

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

I have one array called A , and i have one realm result list called B. Now i have to filter my B based on the values contains in A. So that, my B will have only values object which contains A.

Here is my code :

```
var peopleObjectId: [String] = ["1", "2", "4", "6"]
var list  = Results<userData>
```

my list contains all the object about the user. Now by using below filter. I have to filer my list value which my peopleObjectId contains

```
list = list.filter(NSPredicate(format: "peopleID CONTAINS %@", peopleObjectId))
```

I know i should not use `peopleObjectId` directly. Not sure how can i achieve this.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The other way round: Replace `CONTAINS` with `IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IN` keyword:

> IN
>
> Left hand expression must appear in collection specified by right hand expression. i.e. name IN {‘Milk’, ‘Eggs’, ‘Bread’}
>
> <sup>Ref: [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/)</sup>

```
let found = list.filter { (user) in
    NSPredicate(format: "SELF IN %@", peopleObjectId)
        .evaluate(with:user.peopleID)
}
```

---

More Reading on `NSPredicate`:

- [NSPredicate by NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nspredicate/)

Comment: Why this cumbersome syntax? `format: "peopleID IN %@", peopleObjectId` is much simpler

Comment: @vadian Well... `SELF` is the whole object that I assume has a `peopleID` property. So I tried `SELF.peopleID` and it didn't work, naturally. I just assumed stuff and tested it in playground.

Comment: `SELF` is not needed at all.

Comment: @vadian `peopleID IN %@", peopleObjectId` was the first thing I tried and it did not work. PS: I later based my answer on assumptions that you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/staticVoidMan/378eaf1c193b5846dca823fc22b2f491)

Comment: @david Careful with this answer as if the OP is expecting a Realm Results object, this won't do that. This will return a swift LazyFilterSequence instead of a Results object. e.g. it's not a Realm Collection so you can't add an observer to them

Comment: @Jay Fair enough. I haven't worked with `Realm` so unaware of it's api. @david go with the other answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simpler is better and there doesn't appear to be a need for NSPredicate.

Also, running a filter using Swift functions will not return a Realm Results object, it returns a LazyFilterSequence, which is not a Realm collection. So those objects cannot be observed and loose some of their Realm-ness.

If you have a bunch of dogs stored in realm and you want to retrieve specific dogs, here's the solution which returns a realm results object

```
var listOfDogsToFind = ["Fido", "Dino", "Sport"]
var results = realm.objects(DogClass.self).filter("dog_name IN %@", listOfDogsToFind)
```